# How to get a clean device tree to build the drivers of the msm8939/snapdragon 615

Tags: bootloader, device-firmware, kernel, radio-firmware, arm-processors

I come to you with many interrogations about qualcomm msm8939 SoC.

I bought the [Archos 50 diamond](http://www.gsmarena.com/archos_50_diamond-7042.php) last year and have since been waiting for archos to make their move regarding android software updates.
As of october 2015 Lollipop has been released but in a beta version, no sign of any progress or any comunication ever since.

Whereas Samsung or others have released binaries and device specific configuration for their boards, archos on the other end seems to have other things on it's plate.

I know the binaries for a specific SoC wich is needed to build android or GNU/linux on embedded systems are sometime proprietary and surely in this instance they are, but..

Even if it's only for limited development purposes, would there be any way, known to man to acquire a personal license for a tailored driver binary?

Or maybe is it possible to get an exhaustive list of specific msm8939 device tree configurations options?

Is it safe to think that i can gather that exhaustive list of parameters from the various sources available on github?

Wherever I look for the device tree of the msm8939 I only find repositories for other phones based on this SoC... with a few minor differences. The only thing worth of mentioning (IMHO) is the work of cyanogen Inc. who signed a partnership with qualcomm regarding snapdragon SoC.

Then again even if Cianogenmod is an open source port of AOSP(Big up to anyone contributing), Cianogen Inc's work for those boards still remains behind closed walls.

That's why I would like to know if it is manageable to use another device tree (based on snapdragon 615/msm8939) to build something worth "risking" flashing?

The 50 diamond appears to be a rebrand of the chinese K-touch Touch7 and it would seem it didn't attract a sufficient amount of good FLOSS developpers for me to find the "good & easy to understand" informations in English or in French.

I've been puzzled about another thing in regard of this rebranding. In my build.prop the board name is msm8916(Snapdragon 410) instead of 39!!!!! How come? Is this a trap? Did they just tricked us Or even worse, did they advertise the wrong board ??

If Archos or K-touch or both did in fact used the msm8916 device tree to build the drivers and Android for this board, wouldn't it be missing a whole world of features?

Maybe someone knows of a good forum or repo wich might house the golden goose!? (not including the Cyanogemod repo)

And by that I mean any curated informations about embedded developement for GNU/linux and/or Android (free as in free beer if possible)

It's a shame for smartphone manufacturers that I can't progress on this matter, with a little luck i would brick the damn thing and would have to buy another one :D

I'll leave to it!
This community rocks!
Thanks in advance and see you around!!
Bye bye etc, etc...

Answer (score 0):

One minor thing I can answer: Archos is not deceiving you by using an SD410. It's just the "platform board" is for SD410, and due to SD410 and SD61x being of the same generation and using the same core architecture, using the same board is alright.

As can be freely verified, many SD S4 Pro (APQ8064) / SD600 (APQ8064T) devices use the board msm8960, because ultimately they're using the same Krait 200/300 cores. That doesn't mean they're dual core instead of quad.

As for the main question, I think it's a bad decision to ever purchase devices from such minor manufacturers if you're looking for development, even if these devices have popular SoCs.